# Factsheet generation in Latex: How to implement a specific design

Tags: automation

Implementing a layout for a university paper in Latex is fairly simple as it does not need many elements. But currently I need to generate automatically reports for a university project. The report will have quite similar elements (not content) like the following example [Link](https://www.ishares.com/us/literature/fact-sheet/agg-ishares-core-u-s-aggregate-bond-etf-fund-fact-sheet-en-us.pdf). For this reason I kindly ask the community whether you could give me some indication how I should start this project. If you already made something similar I would appreciate if you could share your example with me and the community. Do you think elaborating such a report with Latex makes sense or do would you suggest using another markup language?

Short remark: The reports will be generated from datasets, which were calculated using R.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could start with the `tcolorbox` package and some TikZ. It is powerful enough to produce such a layout and has quite exhaustive documentation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.